# Approximating a polygon with a circle

Tags: python, computational-geometry

Well, approximating a circle with a polygon and Pythagoras' story may be well known. 
But what about the other way around?

I have some polygons, that should be in fact circles. However, due to measurement errors they are not. So, what I'm looking for is the circle that best "approximates" the given polygon.

In the following figure we can see two different examples.

[image]

My first Ansatz was to find the maximum distance of the points to the center as well as the minimum. The circle we are looking for is maybe somewhere in between.

Is there any algorithm out there for this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the method of least squares.  [Here is a PDF file](http://www.emis.de/journals/BBMS/Bulletin/sup962/gander.pdf) of a paper written on finding a circle using the method of least squares.
It might be a tad complex for what you're doing though. If the points are roughly a circle, you can probably find a more elementary  method that will work just fine.

Comment: Least squares seems like the way to go if you already know the center. It essentially becomes a curve-fitting problem with polar coordinates.

Comment: Check the [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform). It leads to a simple circle detection solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use `scipy` to best-"fit" a circle onto my points. You can get a starting point for the center and radius by a simple center-of-mass calculation. This works well if the points are uniformly distributed over the circle. If they are not, as in the example below, it is still better than nothing!

The fitting function is simple because a circle is simple. You only need to find the radial distance from your fit circle to your points as the tangent (radial) surface will always be the best fit.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from scipy.optimize import fmin
import scipy

# Draw a fuzzy circle to test
N = 15
THETA = np.random.random(15)*2*np.pi
R     = 1.5 + (.1*np.random.random(15) - .05)
X = R*np.cos(THETA) + 5
Y = R*np.sin(THETA) - 2

# Choose the inital center of fit circle as the CM
xm = X.mean()
ym = Y.mean()

# Choose the inital radius as the average distance to the CM
cm = np.array([xm,ym]).reshape(1,2)
rm = cdist(cm, np.array([X,Y]).T).mean()

# Best fit a circle to these points
def err((w,v,r)):
    pts = [np.linalg.norm([x-w,y-v])-r for x,y in zip(X,Y)]
    return (np.array(pts)**2).sum()

xf,yf,rf = scipy.optimize.fmin(err,[xm,ym,rm])  

# Viszualize the results
import pylab as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

# Show the inital guess circle
circ = plt.Circle((xm, ym), radius=rm, color='y',lw=2,alpha=.5)
ax.add_patch(circ)

# Show the fit circle
circ = plt.Circle((xf, yf), radius=rf, color='b',lw=2,alpha=.5)
ax.add_patch(circ)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That works fine only if there no actual outliers, see http://i.imgur.com/pki3Nn7.png for a result after adding one outlier. If the measurement errors do not include this type of error, then this approach is mostly fine indeed.

Comment: @mmgp Agreed. I went with the assumption from the OP, "I have some polygons, that should be in fact circles" that the underlying points are perturbed circles. The nice thing is that you can easily get a fit error out of this, and you can repeat the fits by removing an errant point or two and rechecking. I also think you can bias against outliers by increasing the err penalty from ^2 to say ^4.

Comment: Basically this is exactly what I did. I like the additional idea of optimizing the best fit. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a simple algorithm would be firstly to calculate the centroid of the points (providing they are usually roughly regularly spaced). This is the circle centre. Once you have that you can calculate the mean radius of the points, giving the radius of the circle.

A more sophisticated answer might be to do a simple minimisation, where you minimise the sum of the distances of the points to the edge of the circle (or distance squared).

Answer (score 0):

There are two different O(n) algorithms for determining the smallest circle you draw that encompasses a series of points on the wikipedia page [smallest-circle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem#cite_note-5). From here it should be fairly easy to draw the second circle, simply determine the center of the circle you found previously, and find the point closest to that point. The radius of the second circle is that.

This may not be exactly what you want, but this is how I would start.

Answer (score 0):

That problem might be the same as the [Smallest-circle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem).

But since you have measurement errors which could include outliers, then RANSAC is a good option instead. See http://cs.gmu.edu/~kosecka/cs482/lect-fitting.pdf for a overview of the method (as well other basic techniques), in http://www.asl.ethz.ch/education/master/info-process-rob/Hough-Ransac.pdf there is more information dedicated to circle fitting.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. Assuming he was finding the location of points on a circle and there is an error in the measurement causing the points to no longer fall on a perfect circle, his goal is not to find the smallest circle that encompass them all but rather the most likely circle that would result in his particular points.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the requirements, yes.

Comment: +1 For introducing me to RANSAC and the nice refs! It seems like it requires specific knowledge of the type of errors and outliers you might encounter in your problem though.

Comment: @Hooked well, yes, it does require quite a few parameters. And if there are too few data points then it is bound to fail.

Comment: Thanks for the useful links. I noticed them for future works. However, it seems to me that my problem is quit "trivial" to use such sophisticated solutions.

Answer (score -1):

It's quite easy to find some approximation:

```
def find_circle_deterministically(x,y):
    center = x.mean(), y.mean()
    radius = np.sqrt((x-center[0])**2 + (y-center[1])**2).mean()
    return center, radius
```

Explained: put the center of the circle to the mean x and mean y of your points. Then, for each point, determine the distance to the center and take the mean over all points. That's your radius.

This complete script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_points = 10
radius = 4
noise_std = 0.3

angles = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,n_points,False)
x = np.cos(angles) * radius
y = np.sin(angles) * radius
x += np.random.normal(0,noise_std,x.shape)
y += np.random.normal(0,noise_std,y.shape)

plt.axes(aspect="equal")
plt.plot(x,y,"bx")

def find_circle_deterministically(x,y):
    center = x.mean(), y.mean()
    radius = np.sqrt((x-center[0])**2 + (y-center[1])**2).mean()
    return center, radius

center, radius2 = find_circle_deterministically(x,y)
angles2 = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100,True)
x2 = center[0] + np.cos(angles2) * radius2
y2 = center[1] + np.sin(angles2) * radius2
plt.plot(x2,y2,"r-")

plt.show()
```

produces this plot:

[image]

This will work good as you have polygons with measurement errors. If your points are not approximately equally distributed over the angles `[0,2pi[`, it will perform poorly.

More generally, you could use optimization.

Comment: No disrespect intended, but how is this different from what I do except without optimization? It will also suffer, as mmgp notes, from any outliers _and_, as you note, fails if the points are not uniformly chosen over the circle.

Comment: Indeed, just to make things fair: http://i.imgur.com/4f5Ip42.png, outlier at (50, 50). RANSAC will find the appropriate circle (yes, I'm selling my answer).

Comment: I wrote my answer before your answer was visible on SO. It was just ment as a starting point for doing optimization. I planned to put some code here from my package `eegpy`, where I do almost the same, but for electrode coordinates in 3d and a sphere: https://github.com/thorstenkranz/eegpy/blob/master/eegpy/plot/topo.py

Comment: And yes, outliers are a problem, but the examples you both created are far away from what OP defined.